# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) windows 10

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Hello guys I have created new ssh key and added to my repo in gitlab, I am working as a contractor but can't connect to the server it's finding my email from gitlab and asking for the pass phrase I have given when I have created the ssh key, but it's not working at all 3 times in a row as the password is not the same and it's giving me the following error  Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) I know that the password I am entering is the correct one.
I am typping ssh -T gitlab.example.net the example is replaced with the repo I need to test the connection.

If you have any advice just let me now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please run ssh with the "-v" command-line flag to print verbose output, then [edit] your question to include the output that it produces when trying to connect to gitlab. Be sure to indicate which key file it's supposed to use for gitlab.

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me: [Go to the solution](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/permission+denied+%28publickey+gssapi-keyex+gssapi-with-mic%29+mac)

Basically you have to activate password authentication.